# Adding Gems to Scala play application

Tags: heroku, playframework, rubygems

I am currently deploying my application on Heroku.

I require access to some gems from within my Scala (Play framework) application. Is there any way to do this? I tried including a Gemfile, but that makes it into a Ruby application. From what I understand their documentation says that it is only possible for Ruby/Rails applications.

Comment: I didn't work with Heroku, but still gems are Ruby packages, and Play framework is Scala, well, framework. I'm not sure what you mean under "require access to some gems from within Scala application", but you certainly can't use Ruby libraries from Scala directly. Certainly, it is possible to use JRuby, but something tells me this is not what you want. Could you please explain what exactly you need to do?

Comment: On my local machine, I trigger a bash command (which is a specific ruby gem command) to get a task done. I need the same gem installed on Heroku where my Play framework is, was wondering if that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

As said, Play is Scala, and so as nothing to do with Ruby gem.